# Command line to list all merge(copies) in subversion?

Tags: svn

How can you list all subversion merges?

For  example:

```
Trunk ____9_____14____20___
          \      \     \
           \______\_____\____
Branch01   10     15    21
```

If I branched on rev 9, and then did a merge at rev 14. What is the subversion command line that identifies rev 15 as a merge from rev14 from trunk? The only way I can tell now is from the log file. However, I know I can issue the following command:

```
svn log –-stop-on-copy svn:<URL>/branches/Branch01
```

and it will stop on rev 10 (branched). Is there a command I can issue, that will list 21, 15, and 10 as copies from trunk?

Comment: svn pg svn:mergeinfo <wc_path/or/URL[@rev]>

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the svn plist command for this...

```
 svn plist -v svn:mergeinfo URL/branches/Branch01
```

will print out the information about the branch

an other way is to use the `--use-merge-history`

```
svn log -v --use-merge-history URL/branches/Branch01
```

EDIT:
The following seemed to me what you are searching for.

```
svn mergeinfo URL/trunk URL/branches/Branch01 --show-revs merged
```

Comment: I tried log and it lists everything, however, I'm trying to only list points where a merged or branch occurred. The plist keeps giving me an error svn: '.' is not a working copy. I'm trying to run this on a repository that is stored on my local machine.  svn plist -v svn:mergeinfo file:///home/iser/svn_repo. Any ideas why plist is giving me this error.

Comment: The svn log command you gave worked ? (svn plist -v svn:mergeinfo svn:<URL>/branches/Branch01) ?

Comment: The svn log command returns all log information for the branch. It does not list only the points for merges. The svn plist returns '.' is not a working copy. This is the exact command I typed: svn plist -v svn:mergeinfo file:///home/dmiller3/svn_repo/branches/Recorder_004

Comment: Well I found out two problems. One rapidsvn does not modify mergeinfo properties when it merges. However, when I switch to rabbitvcs, it does. Then when I run the above commands, it all works. Thanks.

Comment: Rapidsvn seemed to be stopped in development...strange.

Answer (score 0):

During each merge operation, the svn:mergeinfo property is changed to record the merge. The mergeinfo will be on `Branch01` in this case. Subversion only records where changes are merged *from*, not where they are merged *to*.

I'm not sure if it's enough in your use case, but you could try to find out all revisions of `Branch01` that have mergeinfo changes?