# how can I test whether a svn branch had been reintegrated?

Tags: svn, branching-and-merging

the book says that reintegrated branch should not be used as it can't accept commits, and in fact recommend to delete it.

How can I test whether a branch had already been reintegrated, if I don't remember?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

svn mergeinfo URL/branches/branchX URL/trunk --show-revs merged

There is a good discussion here for more details:
[so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3806775/command-line-to-list-all-mergecopies-in-subversion)

Comment: thanks. looks like the command I need, but... it does not produce any output. I am sure I merged the branch as I have it's feature on the trunk. Any ideas why this might be?